# Creating a mutation component

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to create a graphql mutation component. My goal is to be able to import it and call registerUser(userInfo) to run  and execute my mutation.

```
const registerUser = (user) => {
  const REGISTER_USER = gql`
  mutation RegisterUser($email: String!, $password: String!, $username: String!){
    RegisterUser(email: $email, password: $password, username: $username){
    id
    username   
    email  
    }
  } 
  `
  const variables = {
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password,
    username: user.username,

  };

  return (
    <Mutation mutation={REGISTER_USER} variables={variables}>
      {(registerUser, { error, data }) => {
        if (error) console.log('error', error);
        if (data) console.log('data', data);

        registerUser()
      }}
    </Mutation>
  )
}

export default registerUser;
```

Comment: What is your question? If the above code is not working, what is not working about it? Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: Its never getting into the mutation, if I log inside the mutation tags it never gets hit. I'm trying to figure out how to run the mutation without having a button inside of it that onClick runs registerUser